# Bypassing "Error Code 43" when installing an old version of a driver

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers

I need to install a very particular driver version for my Intel GPU. Once installed, Windows 10 20H2 refuses to enable it showing "Error Code 43":

[image]

Is there a way to bypass this lock and keep using this version?

Comment: Try to find in the Event Viewer more information about the error.

Comment: Its not a lock, it is an incompatible driver, no workaround for that.